# Saw a dream or had a dream

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Is the first one possible or completely wrong?

> I saw a dream where ...

or

> I had a dream where ...

Comment: You have a dream, but often see something **in** a dream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Had a dream" is normal." You might describe something you saw when you had a dream, but "saw a dream" is not idiomatic.
That said, one might use that phrase in some creative expression, to force looking at things differently.